# Displaying rows with 3 columns in boostrap in my partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am passing a Model into my partial view. The model contains and array of an object. This partial view is going to be used to display a blog post. But I want the blog post to display content in rows were each row would contain 3 columns.
But unfortunately I dont know how to write the multi-dimensional array to do this.

My Model is below

```
public class TopicView
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string PostedDate { get; set; }

        public string IconName { get; set; }

        public string FrontImage { get; set; }

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public string Briefing { get; set; } //This is going to contain the summary information about each blog post

        public string Details { get; set; }

        public string CommentNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Partial View below

```
@model IEnumerable<LiveChatPrototype.Mvc.Areas.Blog.Models.TopicView> 



    @foreach(var val in Model)
    {

        <!-- Post Row -->
    <div class="row post_row">

        <!-- Post -->
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="post">

                <div class="img">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="~/Usedtemplate/users/img/@val.FrontImage" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h5><a href="blogpost.html">@val.Subject.</a></h5>
                    <span class="date">@val.PostedDate.</span>
                    <p>
                        @val.Briefing
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="author_box">
                    <h6>Alejandra Galvan</h6>
                    <p>Creative Director</p>
                </div>
                <a class="plus_wrapper" href="#">
                    <span>&#43;</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    }
```

Comment: Don't really understand your view code. It looks like you're creating one "post" per row. Are you trying to subdivide this post into columns?

Comment: Yep. That's exactly the problem. Move your div with class "row" outside of the loop.

Comment: Yeah that is the code snippet that I have written for now. But my challenge in a case were there are lot of rows in the array. I want a multiple that would have 3 columns. I kind of lost on how to write a multi-dimensional array to display rows and 3 boostrap columns.

Comment: It seems like you actually do need to enumerate the model. I would suggest just changing the view code for the "post" to actually be arranged in columns. You don't need multidimensional arrays. This is totally subjective and I don't think we're going to capture your intent by attempting to answer this question.

Comment: would not mind if any one could help me with an algorithm so that I implement.

Comment: 3 Posts per row or 1 Post per row with 3 columns?

Comment: 1 row would show 3 post. so if they 6 post that means there would be 2 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using for loops instead of a foreach.

```
@model IEnumerable<LiveChatPrototype.Mvc.Areas.Blog.Models.TopicView> 

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i = i + 3)
    {

            <!-- Post Row -->
        <div class="row post_row">

            @for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if(i + j < Model.Count())
                {
                    var val = Model.Skip(i + j).First();
                    <!-- Post -->
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="post">

                            <div class="img">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="~/Usedtemplate/users/img/@val.FrontImage" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text">
                                <h5><a href="blogpost.html">@val.Subject.</a></h5>
                                <span class="date">@val.PostedDate.</span>
                                <p>
                                    @val.Briefing
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author_box">
                                <h6>Alejandra Galvan</h6>
                                <p>Creative Director</p>
                            </div>
                            <a class="plus_wrapper" href="#">
                                <span>&#43;</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }

        </div>
    }
```

Comment: tanks alot would try it and feedback.

Comment: @user3576600 I realised that the code will not run when you don't fill the entire row with 3 posts. I have added an if statement inside the second for loop to fix this.

Comment: tans alot. I am trying to implement now. I am grateful